# Need help with isomorphic binary structures

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(S,*)$ and $(T,o)$ be isomorphic binary structures. Show that $(S,*)$ is a group if and only if $(T,o)$ is a group

Approach: We have to show both directions.

if $(S,*)$ is a group then $(T,o)$ is a group.

I am having problems showing that for every element a in $(T,o)$, $a^{-1} \in (T,o) $. I already proved the first two conditions.

Comment: What means "isomorphic binary structures"?

Comment: it means that there exists an $f$ such that $f$ is bijective and $f$ is homomorphic from $(S,*)$ to $(T,o)$

Comment: Ok. If $f:(T,\circ)\rightarrow (S,*)$ is an isomorphism, then for all $a$ in $(T,\circ)$ there is $b$ in $(S,*)$ such that $f(a)=b$, hence $a=f^{-1}(b)$. Now, note that $a\circ f^{-1}(b^{-1})=f^{-1}(b)\circ f^{-1}(b^{-1})=f^{-1}(b*b^{1})=f^{-1}(e_{S})=e_{T}$, where $e_{S}$ and $e_{T}$ are the identity of $(S,*)$ and $(T,\circ )$, respectively. Similarly, $f^{-1}(b^{-1})\circ a=e_{T}.$ We prove that $a^{-1}=f^{-1}(b^{1}).$

Comment: @Rafael Holanda How do you know that the identity element in S is mapped by the identity element in T?

Comment: How $e_{T}$ is the identity, then $f(e_{T})=f(e_{T}\circ e_{T})=f(e_{T})*f(e_{T})$. Since $(S,*)$ is a group, $f(e_{T})$ has inverse and so $e_{S}=f(e_{T})$.

Comment: you said $f^{-1}(e_S)=e_T$, but in your notation $f^-1(e_S)$ is not in S. It's in T, so I think you are saying there is an inverse because there is an inverse

Comment: $f$ is bijective. Since $e_{S}=f(e_{T})$ then $f^{-1}(e_{S})=e_{T}$. Indeed, we need to show that the identity element in $S$ is mapped by the identity element in $T$, but done it the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in T$. Let $f: S \rightarrow T$ be an isomorphism. Then there is $b \in S$ such that $a = f(b)$. Now 
$$a \circ f(b^{-1}) = f(b) \circ f(b^{-1}) = f(b *b^{-1}) = f(e_{S})=e_T,$$
the last equality you probably showed in proving the other two conditions. This shows $f(b^{-1})$ is an inverse for $a$ in $S$. For the 'only if' part, one only has to prove $f^{-1}$ is a homomorphism of binary structures, then the proof is completely analogous to the proof of the first assertion (just flip $f$ and $f^{-1}$, and $S$ and $T$). So, let $c, d \in T$. Then $$f(f^{-1}(c) \circ f^{-1}(d))=f(f^{-1}(c)) * f(f^{-1}(d)=c*d,$$
so $$f^{-1}(c) \circ f^{-1}(d) = f^{-1}(c*d).$$